# Where are the userspecific windows themes saved?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, administrator, themes

I have a user account named "Paedow". On this account I saved a Windows Theme with wallpaper and sounds and so on...
Now I logged on as "Administrator". I have full access to every file on the computer but I can´t find the themefile. 
**Does anybody know where these "temporary/userspecific" themes are saved?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regional themes:
`%SystemRoot%\Globalization\MCT`

Installed themes:
`%SystemRoot%\Resources\Themes`

Per-user installed and OEM themes:
`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

Current active theme:
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`